# I have a for loop nested within my while loop, what is causing an infinite loop within my code?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop, bisection

I'm new to Python and coding in general.  I am trying to use a while loop with a nested for loop to calculate the lowest % of salary that can be saved that will reach the savings goal within 36 months.  The code also includes functions to apply a semi-annual raise to the salary every 6 months and to apply interest gained to the savings.

When I run my code it results in an infinite loop and I haven't been able to see what is causing it.

```
total_cost = 1000000
semi_annual_raise = 0.07
down_payment = 0.25*total_cost
starting_salary = float(input("What is your annual salary?: "))
monthly_salary = starting_salary/12.0
r = 0.04
steps = 0
epsilon = 100
low = 0
high = 10000
portion_saved = (high + low)/2.0
current_savings = 0
raise_counter = 0

while abs(current_savings - down_payment) > epsilon:
    current_savings = 0

    for months in range(36):
        current_savings += (current_savings*r/12) + (monthly_salary* 
        (portion_saved/10000))

        if raise_counter == 6:
            monthly_salary += monthly_salary*semi_annual_raise
            raise_counter = 0
        raise_counter += 1

    if current_savings < down_payment:
        low = portion_saved
    else:
        high = portion_saved
    portion_saved = (high + low)/2.0
    steps += 1
    raise_counter = 0
print ("Number of steps =", steps)
print ("Optimal % to save:", portion_saved/10000)
```

Comment: `current_savings` goes only up and `down_payment` does not change? In this case the condition `abs(current_savings - down_payment) > epsilon` will be `True` forever.

Comment: @Poolka How do I reset current_savings to 0 for the beginning of each iteration of the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

Why have you used `(monthly_salary*portion_saved/10000` ? Since you need to add the `portion_saved` to the `current_savings` each month, i would recommend you to use

`current_savings+=(current_savings*r/12) + portion_saved`

I think you can also simplify the process by finding the % to be saved using the below formula

`monthly_salary*(save_percent/100)* 36 = down_payment-epsilon`